# Unable to compile j2ee project

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

**Error: Reference file contains errors (http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_4.xsd)**  while building java project. I have mentioned web.xml file.

web.xml :

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Online</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Wat error are you getting?

Comment: What servlet container are you running on? Try to bump the version from 2.4 to the 2.5 spec (a maintenance release for 2.4). `<web-app id="WebApp_ID" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">`

Comment: @Andreas Issue is not resolved your provided xml.